# Format specifier in <inttypes.h> causes warning in cross-platform compatibility

Tags: c, compiler-warnings, format-specifiers, stdint

I am using library `<inttypes.h>` (`<stdint.h>`) for compatibility across platforms in usigned types. When compiling on my MacOSX with `-Wall` options no warnings arise, while on Ubuntu 20.04 I get

```
mvmpi.c: In function ‘main’:
mvmpi.c:33:9: warning: format ‘%u’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int *’, but argument 6 has type ‘uint16_t *’ {aka ‘short unsigned int *’} [-Wformat=]
   33 |         "%"PRIu32"%"PRIu32"%lf%"PRIu16, &N, &M, &L, &SN) != EOF) {
      |         ^~~                                         ~~~
      |                                                     |
      |                                                     uint16_t * {aka short unsigned int *}
In file included from stdbasic.h:33,
                 from mvmpilib.h:8,
                 from mvmpi.c:4:
/usr/include/inttypes.h:103:19: note: format string is defined here
  103 | # define PRIu16  "u"
```

The formatting complains about variable `SN` which is declared to be `uint16_t` variable and then it uses `"%"PRIu16` format specifier, but surprisingly it appears that `PRIu16` is defined in C sources libraries as `unsigned int`, while `uint16_t` would be (regularly) `short unsigned int`.

What is going on here? How to solve and mantain cross platform compatibility? <strike>Of course `uint16_t` from documentation is defined with *at least 16 bits*, but if the format specifier is more, then also it must be bigger in order to maintain coherence.</strike>

Comment: "Of course `uint16_t` from documentation is defined with *at least* 16 bits" No. `uintN_t` is defined to be *exactly* N bits. ([N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 7.20.1.1 Exact-width integer types)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`PRIu16` is for *printing* `uint16_t`.

You have to use `SCNu16` for *reading* `uint16_t`.

Also you have to use `SCNu32`, not `PRIu32`, for reading `uint32_t`.

Comment: `unsigned short int` will be promoted to `int` or `unsigned int` when it is passed to `printf()` for printing. Explicitly specifying the **short** part may increase safety when wrong data is passed, but not specifying that won't affect the behavior on correct usage.

Comment: What a shame, pardon me sir, and thanks for your response. BTW the same error did not come out with the other `PRIu32`... That triggered my brain somehow.